# How to add css to a JavaFx element

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to add a an external **.css** file to a Java FX scene graph as follows:

```
File f = new File("../theming/css/test.css");
scene.getStylesheets().clear();
scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
```

**test.css**

```
.custom-background {
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-padding: 15;
    -fx-spacing: 10;
}

.label {
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-opacity: 0.6;
}
```

The style classes get added well, except where I try to add a custom class to an element:

```
Hbox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.setSpacing(10);
hbox.setMinSize(400, 300);
hbox.getStyleClass().add("custom-background");
```

That doesn't get picked up.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you define twice `-fx-background-color` in 2 classes?

Comment: Sorry @NicolasFilotto. Please ignore that. I edited that out of the question. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to convert the file name to a `URL` yourself. Instead use the build in methods of the `File` class:

```
scene.getStylesheets().setAll(f.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

This assumes the file is located at the specified path relative to the current working directory when the application is run. In most cases using a relative file path is a bad idea, since running from a different directory will break the program. It would be preferable to include the css file as resource.