# How to add an external image via CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx

Please consider the following project structure

```
base_folder
          |
          |_ MyApp
          |    |
          |    |_ src
          |        |
          |        |_controllers (Controllers)
          |             |_MyClass.java
          |
          |_ themming
              |
              |_ icons
              |     |
              |     |icon.png
              |
              |_ style (css)
                    |
                    |_myStyle.css
```

In **MyClass.java**

```
HBox root = new HBox();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 605);

File f = new File("../themming/style/myStyle.css");
try {
    root.getStylesheets().setAll(f.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

root.getStyleClass().add("custom-background");
```

In **myStyle.css**

```
.custom-background {
    -fx-padding: 15;
    -fx-spacing: 10;
    -fx-font-size: 17pt;
    -fx-background-image: url("../icons/icon.png"));
    -fx-background-size: 22 22;
    -fx-background-position: 0 0;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Every other style class gets picked apart from anything to do with the image.

I've tried all variations of possible urls:

```
File f = new File("themming/style/myStyle.css");
File f = new File("../themming/style/myStyle.css");
File f = new File("../../themming/style/myStyle.css");
```

and even placing **themming** in different locations relative to the project root, but to no success.

What am I missing in all this? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: There is no `icon.png` is the displayed file tree

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: Still, `images/icon.png` is not displayed. But in any case, is the `themming` folder a source folder? And how are you running the application?

Comment: **themming** is a folder completely outside the project @Tunaki

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev Then uses a relative path to this directory !

Comment: Could you please give me a simple illustration, maybe as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:

```
.custom-background {
-fx-padding: 15;
-fx-spacing: 10;
-fx-font-size: 17pt;
-fx-background-image: url("../icons/icon.png"));
-fx-background-size: 22 22;
-fx-background-position: 0 0;
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this method directly :

```
/* "pathToTheMainFolder" : All directories before reaching "themming" */
String path = "file:C:/Users/UserName/pathToTheMainFolder/themming/style/style.css";
root.getStylesheets().add(path);
```

And the icon should be relative to where your css file is located :

```
.custom-background{
/*return to the previous folder "themming" and enter to "icons"*/
-fx-background-image:url("..//icons/icon.png");
}
```

**Note** : For the first path (css file) you can use the method that @fabian has advised you [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41642611/6722667)